# How to reliably discover Marathon URL

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

Since `webui_url` entry in Mesos state JSON is optional, one can try the luck with `hostname` (which is also optional).

However, if both of the above entries are missing from Mesos state, is there any other way to reliably discover where Marathon API server is listening?

<s>Furthermore, if a Marathon instance is migrated to another location, Mesos `webui_url` seems to retain the old, stale value. This looks like a bug? Is there any workaround?</s>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you should be able to use the Mesos UI ("Frameworks" -> "Active Frameworks") to find the `marathon` framework.

If the hostname resolution of the host Marathon is running on works correctly, you should be able to click on the link of the "host" column and be redirected to the Marathon UI.

See

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/command-line-flags.html

> `--hostname` (Optional. Default: hostname of machine): The advertised hostname that is used for the communication with the mesos master. The value is also stored in the persistent store so another standby host can redirect to the elected leader. Note: **Default is determined by `InetAddress.getLocalHost`**.

Comment: I see now that there is default, so `hostname` will always be there. However, that still leaves port as possibly being different than `8080`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the background of your question? Normally, Marathon should register as framework correctly, and with the described method above, should also have set the correct port. I *never* had problems with this... So, do you? Or is this just hypothetically asked? You manually start Marathon on some host(s), so I don't really see an point in "discovering"...

Comment: This is a hypothetical question about potential situation that I have not encountered yet. I am accessing Mesos `/master/state` programmatically. Since Marathon `hostname` will always be there, but `webui_url` may not be, I wonder how likely is it that the port will be different from default 8080? And I realize there is no firm answer to that - if someone decides, they can change the port; so, at this point, I'm just wondering what are people's experiences with it.

Comment: I got the answer - the documentation first says optional(default:none), but later says `If not set, the url to the leading instance will be sent to Mesos.`. Confusing, but it looks like Marathon `webui_url` should always be in mesos state. Thanks for your help, though.